# Job service causes parser error in Android Xamarin

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.forms, background, jobservice

I need to download some files in the background for which i used the job service . When i tried to deploy the application in android device version 7.0, an error occur saying "There was a problem while parsing the package". Here is my code

```
public class RegisterJobService:Activity
{
    public static void SchelduleJob(Context context)
    {
        try
        {
            long REFRESH_INTERVAL = 90 * 1000;
            JobInfo.Builder builder;
            JobInfo jobInfo;

            Java.Lang.Class javaClass = Java.Lang.Class.FromType(typeof(BackgroundAgentService));
            ComponentName component = new ComponentName(context, javaClass);
            builder = new JobInfo.Builder(0, component).SetPeriodic(REFRESH_INTERVAL);

            jobInfo = builder.Build();
            JobScheduler jobScheduler = (JobScheduler)context.GetSystemService(JobSchedulerService);
            jobScheduler.Schedule(builder.Build());

        }
        catch (System.Exception ex)
        {
        }
    }
}
```

//Code for Background Job Service

```
[Service(Name = "SampleTestApp.Helper.BackgroundAgent", Permission =
 "android.permission.BIND_JOB_SERVICE")]
public class BackgroundAgentService : JobService
{
    public override bool OnStartJob(JobParameters @params)
    {
        Log.Debug("BATest", "BackgroundAgentService-2/---------OnStartJob////clas");
        return true;
    }

    public override bool OnStopJob(JobParameters @params)
    {
        //throw new NotImplementedException();
        Log.Debug("BATest", "BackgroundAgentService/////++++++++++++OnStopJob/////2/////clas");
        return true;
    }
}
```

I found that when i remove the following code,there is no parser error but 'SchelduleJob' method goes to exception saying 'Java.Lang.IllegalArgumentException: No such service ComponentInfo'.

> [Service(Name = "SampleTestApp.Helper.BackgroundAgent", Permission =
>   "android.permission.BIND_JOB_SERVICE")]

Also i tried to add the permission in manifest file which is not working.

```html
<application >
  <service android:Name="SampleTestApp.Helper.BackgroundAgentService" android:enabled="true" android:permission="android.permission.BIND_JOB_SERVICE" android:exported="true" />
 </application>
```

Anyone have idea on this please?